# Material design on iOS

Tags: android, ios, material-design

It's a good idea to use Google Material Design on a iOS project?

I'm working on a project that works on iOS and Android, on Android we use Material Design, but when I try to make things at same way on iOS, the UX is not so good, it's just my perception or someone had the same experience before?

Comment: your question is good

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with some of Google Apps, it's perfectly possible to use material design on iOS. Actually, Material Design is not a platform specific design.

It'll "break" the Look and Feel with the rest of the system? Yes, kinda. But you definitely can do that and achieve good results and nice UX.

Some good examples are: [Youtube](https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/youtube/id544007664?mt=8), [Hangouts](https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/hangouts/id643496868?mt=8), [Google Maps](https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/google-maps/id585027354?mt=8).

And a non-Google example: [Homeslice](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/homeslice/id705613904?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4).

[image]

Thing is, you're probably going to have to develop some components/widgets to achieve that.

You can read more about Material Design [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html). And there's a loooong discussion on this matter [here](https://www.designernews.co/stories/27078-ask-dn-what-do-you-think-about-using-material-design-on-ios).

Comment: Have you ever seen a app on iOS that isn't made by google?

Comment: Yeah. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Material Design is not specifically targeted towards a platform. Its a design specification with a set of guidelines to build any system. The guidelines are specified to achieve better UX.

So you should be able to build a material design themed application for any target devise. If you are specific to ios, you could get some inspiration by looking at some of the sample apps built based on the theme. Google inbox app or the [material design sample app](https://polymer-topeka.appspot.com/)

Comment: The link is broken.